# Prawn: how to remove all borders from a table?

Tags: ruby, prawn

I'm working with Prawn gem and creating a table. I want to remove all its borders. I can't find this facility in the documentation.

How do I do that?

Comment: table_data = [
       ["a1:", "a2"],
       ["b1", "b2"]
     ]

     pdf.table(table_data, :width => 300, :cell_style => { :border_width => 0 })

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the documentation for the [prawn gem tables](http://rubydoc.info/gems/prawn-layout/0.8.4/Prawn/Table).

According to the "Constructor Details" section, you can pass a variety of `:border_<x>` options to the constructor... I'd suggest trying to pass a value of `:border_width => 0` to your table constructor. (note: not tested - try it yourself and see what happens)

Comment: where do you see :border_x?

Comment: 'x' stands for 'put stuff here'

Comment: please look at my update

Comment: this worked for me: ---------> table customer_items do      
   
   # border details
   self.cells.borders = []
  end